# Documentation for FTDI low level commands for Synchronous FIFO

Tags: ftdi

I am wishing to use the Sync FIFO interface of a FT232H on a custom board from python on a RaspberryPi.  I would use [PyFTDI](https://github.com/eblot/pyftdi), but PyFTDI doesn't implement the Sync FIFO interface mode.  The constant for the Sync FIFO mode is [defined in PyFTDI but never used](https://github.com/eblot/pyftdi/search?q=SYNCFF).  I plan on accessing Sync FIFO by using [PyUSB](https://pyusb.github.io/pyusb/) directly with PyFTDI as a reference.  However as PyFTDI doesn't ever use the Sync FIFO mode, I don't know what FTDI commands are used for the mode on the USB endpoints.  The documentation I have been able to find from FTDI tell how to use the proprietary library as opposed to the low level command structure actually sent to the chip.  I have done a bit of searching, but FTDI provides many documents and it is a bit of information overload.

Does anyone know where the documentation is which covers the low level command codes and arguments which are sent to the FTDI USB end points?  I am assuming the authors of PyFTDI were referencing something besides wire sniffing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to their knowledge base](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Knowledgebase/index.html?doftdidistributedriversourc.htm) FTDI provides an API document under an NDA for some circumstances.

> In some circumstances, it may be desirable to develop a custom driver for an exotic operating system or an embedded system.  In these circumstances, an API document may be obtained from FTDI under NDA to allow driver development for FTDI devices.  To request a copy of the API document, please contact FTDI Support support1@ftdichip.com.